# Load external property file in multi module maven project and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, multi-module

I am currently working on a Spring Boot multi module application with maven. When I package the app, the final jar contains inside one jar for each module.

In some modules, I use a property file that I storage inside each module and load it using

```
getClass().getClassLoader().GetResource(...);
```

but now I want to put all these properties files in one external folder in order to be able to modify them easily.

I have tried changing the classpath and different ways of loading properties in code, but I am not able to load the external file from my modules. However, application.properties is loaded for the external folder without problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not using the default mechanisms of Spring Boot for properties/configuration etc. ?

Comment: Basicly for reducing dependency with Spring Boot